# Illustrator: Trouble with font size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-size

I am using Adobe illustrator Cs5.1 on Mac. I am having trouble making with font size. In short, I will select two blocks of text and set them as the same font and the same size. However, they appear completely different sizes. Horizontal scale and vertical scale are both set at 100%. Problem exists with multiple fonts. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top line is most likely set to **superscript**.

Select the text, choose `Show Options` from the **Character Panel** menu, then click the Superscript button.

[image]

<sub>CS6 screenshot, but should be the same in CS5.</sub>

In CS5 you may need to *uncheck* the "superscript" option in the Character panel menu. I can't launch CS5 to check.

Comment: @abe You can somewhat see this in you screenshot: the 'smaller' type has relatively more space below it inside its black selection bar than does the 'larger' type.